# Unable to start service Intent: initOpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, android-intent, android-studio, camera

i tried to initialize openCv in order to use the camera. the libraries are initialized successfully, but when i tried to initialize openCc it is returning this error:

```
01-17 14:19:24.606 8747-8747/com.pettracker.objecttracker E/OpenCV could not be loaded!: CameraTest::CameraPreview
01-17 14:19:24.606 1267-1476/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND pkg=org.opencv.engine } U=0: not found
01-17 14:19:24.606 1267-1278/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@b15c6c98
```

i am trying to use openCv library to use the camera for colour tracking. the code is illustrated as below:

```
public CameraPreview(ICameraPreviewCallback context, IFrameProcessor frameProcessor) {
        super((Context)context);
        mContext = context;
        System.out.println(mContext);
        mFrameProcessor = frameProcessor;
        if (!loadOpenCV()) {
            Log.e("OpenCV could not be loaded!", TAG);
        }
    }


private boolean loadOpenCV() {
    return OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_2, (Context)mContext, this);
}
```

In addition, i have modified initOpenCv so that i won't run into the implicit calling of the intent, the code is illustrated below:

```
public static boolean initOpenCV(String Version, final Context AppContext,
        final LoaderCallbackInterface Callback)
{
    AsyncServiceHelper helper = new AsyncServiceHelper(Version, AppContext, Callback);
    Intent intent = new Intent("org.opencv.engine.BIND");
    intent.setPackage("org.opencv.engine");
    if (AppContext.bindService(intent,
            helper.mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        AppContext.unbindService(helper.mServiceConnection);
        InstallService(AppContext, Callback);
        return false;
    }
}
```

what could be the cause of this error? and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you have used OpenCv Static Initilization.
Have you copied the native libs in the project directory
you can have a look to this tutorial [here](http://androidsimpleasthat.blogspot.in/2016/01/android-opencv-static-initilization.html)

```
//try useing this code for initilization of OpenCv insted of yours.
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

        }
            break;
        default: {
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        }
            break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this,
                mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Comment: have uploaded the wrong snippet of my project code, the correct version is illustrated in the edited version of my question above and i have modified the errors to clarify. in addition, i have already added the native libs in my project.

Comment: i have edited the answer for you and one more thing while using OpenCVLoader.initAsync() you don't need to add the native libs. you will just have to download the opencv manager from the play store

Comment: thank you so much, i download the latest version openCv manager on my emulator and everything went fine.

Comment: it turned out i didn't download ndk on my android studio, the tutorial you provided and your comment helped me to find that out. thanks for saving my day !!

Comment: if you would accept the answer that would be nice of you